# Overwriting variable on form submit

Tags: php, forms, file, variables, overwrite

im trying to overwrite a variable stocked on a txt file using a form, here's the form code :

```
 <form action="test.php" method="POST" NAME="action1">

            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $amount +10 ?>">

    <input type="button" value="increment" onclick="window.document.action1.submit()">


    </form>
```

and here's test.php file :

```
<?php

$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$amount = 0;
fwrite($fh, $amount);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

i know there are many wrong thing with my code but it would be amazing if someone tells me what wrong with the form code; thanks for your time .

Comment: You don't define `$amount` in either of the two PHP programs.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names are extremely confusing. You're putting a value `$amount + 10` in a field named `name`? And you never define `$amount` before you try to output it, so that's going to give you errors. What are you expecting to happen there?

I *think* the variable you are trying to save is `$_POST['name']`, like this:

```
<?php

$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $_POST['name']);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

But you *really* need to validate the data before using it; otherwise, a user could save all sorts of bad stuff in your txt file.

**Edit:** Based on the comments, you want to read from the file, then increment the variable when the user submits the form. A few thoughts:

1. You have no code for reading from the file. Get that part working first.
2. This is strange. This lets the user enter anything, not just a number. This is almost certainly not what you want to do.
3. You need to plan out what you want and implement it in steps. Your current code doesn't bear much resemblance to what you want. This is partially because you haven't thought through where your data is coming from and going. You might find a tutorial on form processing with PHP helpful.

Comment: what im trying to do is when the user clicks on submit button the variable $amount on the txt file becomes $amount+10 (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You want to add 10 *after* the submission? Or before it? This is all very unclear.

Comment: Well, then see my answer. You also have to read from the file at some point; there's no code for that in your question.